# Capybara doesn't fill correctly some fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm starting to use capybara to test my rails apps, but now I have a problem.

From time to time, capybara fills the content of two fields in only one, producing errors. This happens in a random way, and I don't have idea about how to prevent it.

For example, the following image was supposed to have "New capybara party" in the first field, and "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" in the second one, but as you see, there was filled bad.

[This image explains the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfdR0.png)
[image]

I'm using rspec with capybara and selenium. The code in the following:

```
context 'User is logged in' do
  it 'creates a party' do
    click_link "Have a party"
    within("#new-party-modal") do
      fill_in 'party_title', with: 'New capybara party'
      fill_in 'party_description', with: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
      fill_in 'party_venue', with: '1392 7th Avenue, San Francisco, California, Estados Unidos'
      fill_in 'party_phone', with: '9106156667'
      fill_in 'party_starts_at', with: DateTime.now+5.days
      click_button 'Continue to step 2'
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you output the code from that modal?

Comment: Sure, here is the code: http://pastebin.ca/3240976
But it doen't happen just in this form. This happens in any part of my application

Comment: Hmm not sure what it could be wrong.. Are you passing `js: true` on this spec? Also you could try to use `poltergeist` instead of `selenium` and see if you have this same behaviour.

Comment: It looks like you have some kind of JavaScript validation in the form that is preventing focus from shifting

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot, I suspect the problem is related to locator. Since the [fille_in](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions:fill_in) uses name, id or label text, you need to be very careful about the uniqueness of them. So, make sure that the *textarea* and *title* elements' selector does not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar case, but my forms has a javascript that saved them after they lose focus so i just

```
page.driver.browser.execute_script('$("your_field").trigger("submit.rails")')
```

after each fill.
Hope it helps.